# How to use SLF4J when there is multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j

When I add the SLF4J logger into my code, I get an error saying, "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings." On the website slf4j.org/codes it states that I should remove them from the class path. However, these two loggers are included in my maven dependencies.  And my whole maven dependency folder is included into the class path. I'm not in charge of what goes into the maven dependencies, so it's not my place to edit it so that it only has one logger dependency inside the maven dependency folder. Can I specify the Java Program so that it only uses one of the loggers instead?

ejay

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace also? Looks like it's just a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out which of your project's dependencies is including an slf4j implementation, then exclude it:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>other-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-id</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                    <!-- or slf4j-jdk14, etc -->
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the good feedback, however I found out what was wrong. It was some settings in Eclipse that I had set that made it give a warning. It basically read the pom.xml file twice therefor calling the slf4j implementations twice, which is why it gave me a warning. Which makes a lot of sense, because my co-worker is using the same pom.xml and his logger is working fine.

Comment: @Ejay Glad you fixed it. You should post that as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: Excluding seems to be a common answer on the internet, but it's problematic because sometimes the dependency actually uses the frickin logging impl's classes, so you get a NoClassDefFound exception at runtime because your exclusion caused the the JAR containing those classes to go missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain you can't adjust the existing maven dependencies to fix the problem, you could make sure your SLF4J binding appears in the classpath first, as the first binding is the one that gets used in the case of multiple bindings.

You'll still get the warning however, but your SLF4J logger will be the one that gets used.

You could also consider utilising maven modules to split the project up into sections so that you can manage the dependencies in each section differently in each module's pom.xml file.